# How to grep regex in python with -1 index

Tags: python

This is my python code:

```
import re
import smtplib
import ssl
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header import Header
from datetime import datetime

with open('all.txt', 'r') as names_file:
    with open('email.yaml', 'r') as emails_file:
        names = names_file.readlines()
        emails = emails_file.readlines()

        for name in names:
            name = name.strip()
            for i, email in enumerate(emails):
                email = re.sub('-', '', email)
                email = re.sub(' ', '', email)
                if re.search(name, email):
                    prev_email = emails[i-1].strip()
                    prev_email = re.sub('-', '', prev_email)
                    prev_email = re.sub(' ', '', prev_email)
                    html = html.format(name=name)
                    print(f"Name: {name}, Email: {prev_email}")
                    break
```

This is `all.txt`:

```
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.12
1.1.1.11
```

This is `email.yaml`:

```
    - emailA@gmail.com
    - 1.1.1.12
    - emailB@gmail.com
    - 1.1.1.1
    - emailC@gmail.com
    - 1.1.1.11
```

When I run `python3 file.py`, this is the output:

```
Name: 1.1.1.1, Email: emailA@gmail.com
```

The issue is because `1.1.1.1` consist `1.1.1.1*`, then all reports are wrong for such IPs.

Expected output:

```
Name: 1.1.1.1, Email: emailB@gmail.com
Name: 1.1.1.12, Email: emailA@gmail.com
Name: 1.1.1.11, Email: emailC@gmail.com
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you expect as a valid result?

Comment: @Ron I updated the question with expected output.

Comment: by using `\b` before and after the name in your regex pattern, you ensure that the name matches as a whole word!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can modify the regular expression pattern to include word boundaries `\b` around the name, check this out :

```
import re

html = "<html><body><h1>Salaam, {name}!</h1></body></html>"

with open('all.txt', 'r') as names_file:
    with open('email.yaml', 'r') as emails_file:
        names = names_file.readlines()
        emails = emails_file.readlines()

        for name in names:
            name = name.strip()
            for i, email in enumerate(emails):
                email = re.sub('-', '', email)
                email = re.sub(' ', '', email)
                if re.search(fr'\b{name}\b', email):
                    prev_email = emails[i-1].strip()
                    prev_email = re.sub('-', '', prev_email)
                    prev_email = re.sub(' ', '', prev_email)
                    html = html.format(name=name)
                    print(f"Name: {name}, Email: {prev_email}")
                    break
```

output :

```
Name: 1.1.1.1, Email: emailB@gmail.com
Name: 1.1.1.12, Email: emailA@gmail.com
Name: 1.1.1.11, Email: emailC@gmail.com
```

good luck !